# Error when add property in ApplicationUser Identity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

i am trying to use Identity,
I want customize the class ApplicationUser by adding property for exemple "CustomeName" but when i try to register i have an error "SQL Exception : Invalid column name"

I've look on my DB and the column is not create in AspNetUsers so i think i've forgot something.

What i've do its :

In ApplicationUser.cs

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
       public string CustomeName {get; set;}
    }
```

In RegisterViewModel.cs

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "CustomeName")]
    public string CustomeName{ get; set; }
```

And in the AccountController.cs, in the method Register

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, CustomeName = model.CustomeName }
```

I've make all migration.

What i've forgot ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you apply migration against database ?

Comment: Yes with : 
    dotnet ef database update

Comment: Check your database and see if migration applied or not.

Comment: It's applied, but still nothing, but I have a new table, who get the name of the class ApplicationUser and have all property (CustomName + same property of table "[AspNetUsers]")
I think i need to modify the register page for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly resolved, I dont know if its my fault but in my migration i've never find the "AddColumn" so i've create a migration who delete the property, comment the delete into migration file, then add again my property and apply again my migration and that works :) thanks @MohsenEsmailpour, for put me on the good way